# FontFamily is added but no changes in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the FontFamily in my Xamarin App. I downloaded the font and add it into the project, but still not changes applied on the text.

**Mobile.App** : **Fonts** (folder)

`catamaran-regular.tff`

**Mobile.App** : **AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportFont("catamaran-regular.ttf")]
```

**Mobile.App** : **App.xml**

```
<Style
    TargetType="Label"
    ApplyToDerivedTypes="true">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="catamaran-regular" />
</Style>
```

**Mobile.App.Views** : **Page.xml**

```
Label
    Text="Hello World!"
    FontSize="18"
    FontFamily="catamaran-regular">
</Label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an Alias to target the font:

```
[assembly: ExportFont("catamaran-regular.ttf", Alias = "CatamaranRegular")]
```

And then use the alias in your elements:

```
<Label
    Text="Hello World!"
    FontSize="18"
    FontFamily="CatamaranRegular">
</Label>
```

If still doesn't work make sure the font is set as an embedded resource; if you are using Visual Studio, select the file and from the properties panel select the option in the Build Action drop-down:

[image: Embedded Resource]